Can I configure the Airflow ECS Executor to allow running tasks to survive scheduler restarts?
I'm testing out Airflow 2.9.0 with the AWS ECS Executor. I noticed that if I restart the scheduler then when it resumes it kills any running ECS tasks. I believe that is indicated by this log message:
airflow-scheduler-1  | [2024-04-19T20:39:29.918+0000] {scheduler_job_runner.py:1654} INFO - Reset the following 1 orphaned TaskInstances:
airflow-scheduler-1  |  <TaskInstance: mydag.mytask manual__2024-04-19T14:44:14+00:00 [running]>

Is that the expected behavior? Is there a configuration option that would allow the executor to simply identify the running task and resume waiting for it to finish?
For reference, the docs for the Kubernetes Executor explicitly state

Because the resourceVersion is stored, the scheduler can restart and continue reading the watcher stream from where it left off. Since the tasks are run independently of the executor and report results directly to the database, scheduler failures will not lead to task failures or re-runs.

I do not see any similar specification of the restart behavior in the ECS Executor docs
